# How to use momet js in EJS views, but get the users local time and not servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs, ejs

I am currently passing Moment js from my server using app.locals.

```
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

I am trying to call the local() function when displaying the time, but it still displays the it is getting from the server.

Is it possible to to use this method to display the time in the users timezone?

Comment: You can ask for timezone in the request and then render time accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS you run in your EJS views will be run on the **server side** and then the result of that will be given to the user. So you won't be able to use moment on the backend to get the users frontend local time.

If you want the users local time you're going to need to get it with frontend JS so you'll need to install the browser version of momentjs and add that into your frontend code. There isn't anyway to get the users local time while on the server side (what if they made a request from Russia and you're server is in Australia for example).

EJS views can be confusing this way because you've got frontend JS which is getting served up to the browser and you've got JS in the templates which is being run on the server.

If you really needed to get the users local timezone for the server side, you could push up the timezone in the initial request (maybe as a url param) and get it that way but if you're doing it for display purposes you do not want to do that.